# Identity 2.1.0 Samples MVC 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

Friends,

Someone from Microsoft sent me a confirmation via email that I could now use the Identity 2.1.0 Alpha Samples in production.

I did not waste anytime and I created an empty template and then open the Package Manager console and typed:
PM> Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Samples -Pre

Now, when I open a view or a layout all the HTML helpers have a red squiggly. I can build and run the application no problem, however, this is very annoying.

Also when I create a strongly typed view, the intelliSense does not work for my lambda expressions and such.

Would someone mind try recreating this issue and finding a possible solution?

All you need to do is create an empty template and then open the Package Manager console and type:
PM> Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Samples -Pre

Thank you,

Comment: Have you installed the Update 2 of visual studio 2013
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42666

Comment: Problem solved. The red squigglies are gone and intelliSense now works. After doing the update it fixed my current project, however I created a new project using Identity Samples and the issue was still there. I closed VS and it is gone. Thanks for the fix!

Comment: How do I mark as answered?

Comment: Great! I accedently answered in comment, but I posted the answere below, please mark as answered :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you installed the Update 2 of visual studio 2013 http://microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42666